# xml.etree.Elementree: Why is text below the tag not being identified

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I wrote this script to scrape the webpage in question (in the code) to an XML file:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

xml = open("import.xml", "w+")
xml.write(urlopen('http://mahmi.org/api/peptides/sourceProteins/241282699').read().decode('utf-8'))
xml.close()
```

When I open the file 'import.xml', I can see the data is there; i.e. the start of the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><sourceProteins><sourceProtein><protein><id>2232238</id><sequence>MLLTNFQNFASLHAVPVAQIRAMEACPLPTEPIRCVIRELDVSKLTPDQLTQLNEVIDGYNKDLAFMIEELHKRANRRYCHGKNFIKWRGLLRAAHAVVHAALPPGMQKTHLLSKGGLQGKMWKTALEDACSTMDRYWRSIQVAVYCELRNKEFYSKLNDAEKYYVGCLLNNTGYLFFDMLDGKTPKPALPNKLKGKLSDPRNLCRKVRATVRRHSRRLPRHGVDRSCSLTTECYSVTQDSQGNQTISVITNTRGKRLLIPVKGKGRIGRTIKIVRDNGKFYLHIPLKTPVVPFEHIPRAPLAAGKATLHCTALDMGYTEVFTDDAGNFYGTELGKTLDAIGRKLDEVYRERNRWHARYRNEKDDKKKLNILRFNLGRKKLDAFETRARARVVCLVNKAINDIMAMRPADVYLIERFGQQFNFAGLSKKTRRKLSGWIRGTIEERFFFKASIHGAKAVYVPASYSSRRCPVCGYVHKTNRNGD</sequence><name>T2D-154A_GL0135792</name></protein><uniprotData><uniprotId>O66401</uniprotId><uniprotOrganism>Aquifex aeolicus (strain VF5)</uniprotOrganism><uniprotProtein>YZ05_AQUAE Putative...
```

So now I want to read in that file, and e.g. print out all text under the uniprotData tag:

[image]

I wrote this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
fileopen = open('import.xml').read()
root = ET.fromstring(fileopen)
for x in root.iter('uniprotData'):
        print(x.text)
```

But the output is 'None'.
Can someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: `uniprotData` has children only, but no text itself.

Comment: You have to loop `x`, which is `<uniprotData>...</uniprotData>`, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you need to iterate one more time over x. Indeed, `x` is of type [xml.etree.ElementTree.Element](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

**Code**:

```
fileopen = open('import.xml').read()
root = ET.fromstring(fileopen)
for x in root.iter('uniprotData'):
    print(type(x))
    # <class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>

    for child in x:
        print("{:20} -> {}".format(child.tag,child.text))
        # uniprotId            -> O66401
        # uniprotOrganism      -> Aquifex aeolicus (strain VF5)
        # uniprotProtein       -> YZ05_AQUAE Putative transposase aq_aa05
        # uniprotGene          -> aq_aa05
```